# how to sort a dynamic array efficiently

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, queue

Strictly speaking, I am writing a path finding algorithm, I have everything ready, but the program works for a long time on large maps, for example 1000 by 1000 (2d int array) can be processed up to 30 seconds.

Everything works well until I start sorting the queue for the next point check
I have not come up with anything better how to sort the queue every time after checking neighboring points, because of this, the program suffers a lot because each time it sorts the array due to one or two new elements and breadth-first search algorithm without sorting the queue works faster than greedy search or A*

Here is the sort method called every time after checking the points

```
class Position {
int x;
int y; }


public static ArrayList<Position> queue = new ArrayList<Position>();
public static int xend, yend;

public static void sorth () {
    for(int i = queue.size()-1; i > 0 ; i--){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++){
            if( Math.sqrt((xend-queue.get(j).x)*(xend-queue.get(j).x) + (yend-queue.get(j).y) * (yend-queue.get(j).y))
                    > Math.sqrt((xend-queue.get(j+1).x)*(xend-queue.get(j+1).x) + (yend-queue.get(j+1).y)*(yend-queue.get(j+1).y)) ){
                Position tmp = new Position();
                tmp.x = queue.get(j).x;
                tmp.y = queue.get(j).y;
                queue.set(j,queue.get(j+1) );
                queue.set(j+1, tmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

New items are added to the end of the queue if the point can be visited
and old ones are removed from the beginning

Comment: Use a [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

Comment: Or at the very least, don't use bubble sort.